# Is $y_i=\alpha+(\beta_1+\beta_2)x_1+\beta_2x_2+\epsilon_i$ a linear regression model?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I know that an OLS model is supposed to be linear in its parameters. I wonder if this model is an OLS model, or can it be turned into one?

Comment: Set $\beta = \beta_1 + \beta_2$. Now does this look linear in the parameters?

Comment: I am not sure because what it means is that there is a constraint between $\beta$ and $\beta_2$ in this case. the parameters affect each other

Comment: The function $(\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2)\to \alpha +  \cdots + \epsilon_i$ is *manifestly* linear from its very form.  Nothing needs to be demonstrated.  Perhaps reading https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638 will help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

$$\begin{align}y_i & =\alpha+(\beta_1+\beta_2)x_1+\beta_2x_2+\epsilon_i\\
\\
& = \alpha+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_1+\beta_2x_2+\epsilon_i\\
\\
& =\alpha+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2(x_1+x_2)+\epsilon_i\end{align}$$

Comment: Still not sure since this model will not be BLUE. It's wrong in the sense that if you take $x*=x_1x_2$ then $x1=\frac{x*}{x_2}$. Isn't that a type of collinearity?

Comment: It looks like you want $x_1+x_2$, not $ x_1x_2$.

Comment: Does that violate an assumption of the gauss-markov theorem? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem

Comment: @RyanVolpi Non-mobile link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem

Comment: @RyanVolpi it does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity

Comment: note that it also means that if $\beta_1>0$ and $\beta_2>0$, then the first coefficient constrained to be greater than the second

Comment: @Y.L I don't think it does. Can you be more specific? Lack of multicollinearity is not an assumption of the gauss markov theorem.

Comment: @RyanVolpi it is. What you find in Wiki is not complete. look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307298/why-is-the-ols-assumption-no-perfect-multicollinearity-so-vital

Comment: @RyanVolpi they typically call it "no perfect colinearity" between regressors

Comment: @Y.L Oh yes, I see.  *Perfect* multicollinearity is different in that it implies one variable is an exact linear function of the other, which is not true in your case. Additionally, that's a requirement to get a unique solution to OLS, which is different  from whether the OLS estimate is BLUE. But in any case, $X_1+X_2$ is not perfectly colinear with $X_1$ except in some trivial case, so I don't think you'll have any issue.